# .NET Core send user to page from method that cannot return Redirect

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method in my controller class that returns a tuple and runs right before the rest of the controller executes:

```
private async Task<(int userId, int userRoleId, bool accountVerified)> GetUserRole()
{
  var identifier = User.Identity.Name;
  var user = await _context.User.Where(x => x.UserEmail == User.identifier).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
  
  //this is an oddly specific condition that differs for every controller class. Causes a compiler error as written
  if (!user.Approved && (user.RoleId == 1 || user.RoleId == 7))
  {
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Notifications");
  }
  //this returns data that is used in the controller methods
  else
  {
     return (user.UserId, user.RoleId, user.Approved);
  }
}
```

I have several controller classes where this method is declared. Currently I have the above mentioned redirect declared in each view method (`Index()`, `Create()`, `Edit()`, etc). It seems a bit of a waste to declare a new authorization policy for every controller that needs this when the logic is already there.

Is there a way to redirect the user without declaring `return RedirectToAction(...)`?

Or am I missing something entirely?

Comment: Yeah, you need to look into MVC/WebApi attributes

Comment: Could you elaborate? I know MVC requires a rout to determine what page is being displayed. Is there any reason I can't create an independant command to redirect the user in response to a given condition?

Comment: You probably want some kind of request filter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to populate properties / reject the request.

Comment: This looks promising. Might take a while to parse the docs, though.